# How to Prove Below Inverse Sin

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove below equation .

$$     \sin^{-1}\frac{3}{5}+\sin^{-1}\frac{8}{17} = \sin^{-1}\frac{77}{85}.$$

I am not able to prove the above equation how can we prove it.

As we know

$  \sin^{-1} = y$ if $\sin y = x$ where $-1\leq x\leq 1, -\pi/2 \leq y \leq \pi/2.$

Comment: You decide what the cosines of the first two angles are, and then apply the addition formula for the sine. There may be slicker, quicker ways of doing it.

Comment: Can you please help me to prove above example

Comment: If the sine of an acute angle is $5/13$, what is the cosine? If the sine of another acute angle is $3/5$. what is the cosine? Now find the sine of the sum-angle from the standard formula $\sin(A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B$.

Comment: I am not in touch with mathematics from last 10 year today i have to start again so lots of issue i am getting

Comment: Well, then, you are to be commended for returning to the world of beauty. To find the cosines, you have to draw a right triangle with hypotenuse $13$ and one leg $5$, and use Pythagoras to find the other leg. Similarly for the other angle. The addition formula for sine is rather more complicated, but has several different proofs that can be found here and there on the web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Remark:** The question has changed from $\sin^{-1}(5/13)+\sin^{-1}(3/5)$ to 
$\sin^{-1}(3/5)+\sin^{-1}(8/17)$. There is no good reason to change the answer below, since the process is basically the same.

**Hint:** Use the "sum" formula $\sin(a+b)=\sin a \cos b+\cos a\sin b$.

If $a$ is the angle between $0$ and $\pi/2$ whose sine is $\frac{5}{13}$, then the cosine of $a$ is $\frac{12}{13}$, since always $\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x=1$.

If $b$ is the angle between $0$ and $\pi/2$ whose sine is $\frac{3}{5}$, then the cosine of $b$ is $\frac{4}{5}$.

You will also need to show that the sum on the left is $\lt \pi/2$.

**Remark:** The notation $\sin^{-1} t$ is a fairly frequent source of confusion. It means the angle between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ whose sine is $t$. It **does not** mean $\frac{1}{\sin t}$. So for example $\sin^{-1}(1)=\pi/2$ and $\sin^{-1}(1/2)=\pi/6$.

Comment: Can you give detail Solution?

Comment: I will, if necessary, write out a complete solution. However, the hints in the current answer are quite detailed, and it would be I think much better if you used them to work out your own solution. If you run into trouble with a detail, I can help.

Comment: Actually from today i started reading again mathematics after 12years so not able to understand so asked details solution how it will prove

Comment: Start calculating $\sin(\sin^{-1}(5/13)+\sin^{-1}(3/5))$, using the addition formula which is at the start of my answer. Note that $\sin(\sin^{-1}(t))=t$, so the only work you will need to do is to work out the cosine terms.

Comment: how to solve Cos(Sin-1(3/5))

Comment: Let $t=\sin^{-1}(3/5)$. Then $\sin t=3/5$. But by a very useful identity we have $\cos^2 t+\sin^2 t=1$. So $\cos^2 t+\frac{9}{25}=1$, and therefore $\cos^2 t=\frac{16}{25}$. Taking square roots, and using the fact that $t$ is between $0$ and $\pi/2$, we get $\cos t=4/5$.  More simply, if $\sin t=3/5$ we are working with the good old $3$-$4$-$5$ right triangle. Draw it. You can read off that $\cos t=4/5$.

Comment: thanks done now first solution after 15year gap

Comment: I get $(5/13)(4/5)+(3/5)(12/13)=56/65$. But you have just changed the question! With the new one I get $(3/5)(15/17)+(8/17)(4/5)=77/85$.

Comment: Yes my question was wrong someone edited value

Answer (score 1):

Let  $\displaystyle\sin^{-1}\frac35= A$

$\displaystyle\implies (i)\sin A=\frac35$ and $(ii)-\frac\pi2< A<\frac\pi2 $ as the [Principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) of sine inverse lies in that range $\displaystyle\implies\cos A>0 \implies \cos A=+\sqrt{1-\left(\frac35\right)^2}=+\frac45$

Similarly for $\displaystyle\sin^{-1}\frac5{13}= B$

Use $\sin(A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B$

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359317/inverse-trigonometry-derivation/359493#359493), $$\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y=$$
$$ \begin{cases} \sin^{-1}(x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}) &\mbox{if } x^2+y^2\le1\text{ or if } x^2+y^2>1\text{ and } xy<0  \\ \pi-\sin^{-1}(x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}) & \mbox{if } x^2+y^2>1\text{ and }x,y>0 \\  -\pi-\sin^{-1}(x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}) & \mbox{if } x^2+y^2>1\text{ and }x,y<0 \end{cases} $$

Comment: 3/5*12/13+4/5*5/13 giving wrong result i am doing something wrong?

Comment: @user110715, You should cross-check the Right Hand side of the Question, if you have understood my method

Comment: I have just started maths again after 15year so lake of knowledge